# XCode Constraints not working as intended

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, ios-autolayout

Okay, I am pulling my hair over this. I am trying to add constraints to this top title, where it is constrained to the top, left, and right of the screen bounds. But, no matter what I do, let it be pin, or automatic constraints, it does not want to stay on the top. If I pin it, I get this:

[image]

If I let xcode do it, then this:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Finally, if I just add left and right constaints, it looks fine in xcode:

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

But, this is how it looks on iphone 6s:

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

The above result is regardless if I add missing constraints to the rest of the items.

I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Doing this for android apps is 10x more easier.

ALSO:

If I add missing constraints to the title and all the below items, I get this:

[image]

Images are squished, and the top title is not aligned with the top of the screen.

Comment: add missing constraints is not the way to go ....

Comment: I get that, but doing it manually is not working either. No matter what I try, xcode does not agree.

Comment: Xcode agrees if you set the proper constraints .... otherwise it just gives you constraints error ... Xcode is not your enemy :)

Comment: It is my enemy, and it certainly is no where near as good as Android Studio in terms of layout design, that's for sure. I can't even simply align the title image to the top. I tried every pinning combination, combinations with height and width, combinations with aspect ratio, anything. It just doesn't agree.

Comment: ok ... whatever it is but I just suggest you what I know :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Unfortunately, I tried and they don't work.

Comment: Can you show the document outline on left hand side in the storyboard that shows all the view and constraints?

Comment: The images [2], [3], [4] are missing.